# Netsuite: Check Payee field in Check form is Vendor or not

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm working with Check form in Transaction > Bank > Write Checks. 
I have to check the Payee type whether it is a Vendor or not. The data inside Payee field is a Record. It link to the form of who order this and pay for it. But I don't know how to check type of data in field like that. So How can I check it?

[This is the Check screen and the Payee field in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvfC5.png)

```js
function beforeLoad(scriptContext) {
    var contextRecord = scriptContext.newRecord;
    var payeeType = contextRecord.getField("entity");
    if(contextRecord.type === context.UserEventType.EDIT || contextRecord.type === context.UserEventType.CREATE){
        if('what can I do to check payee type')
        //Do something if Payee Type is Vendor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't get the type from the "entity" field, it just gives you back the internal id of the entity. My best recommendation would be to do a sort of guess and check strategy where you could look to see if the entity was a vendor or employee. Here is an example using your script.

```
function beforeLoad(scriptContext) {
    var contextRecord = scriptContext.newRecord;
    var payeeId = contextRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'entity' });
    if(contextRecord.type === context.UserEventType.EDIT || contextRecord.type === context.UserEventType.CREATE){
        var internalIdObj = search.lookupFields({ type: search.Type.VENDOR, id: payeeId, columns: ['internalid'] });
        if (Object.keys(internalIdObj).length > 0) {
            // Must be a vendor so do logic here
        }
    }
}
```

You can switch our `search.Type.VENDOR` with `search.Type.EMPLOYEE` or any other record type to check those.